# range of the bins matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot histogram using matplotlib.
I am just wondering how I may set up range `(<9.0,9.0-10.0,11.0-12.0,12.0-13.0.. max element in an array)` of bins.
<9.0 stands for elements smaller than 0.9

I have used the smallest and biggest value in an array:

```
plt.hist(results, bins=np.arange(np.amin(results),np.amax(results),0.1))
```

I'll be grateful for any hints

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: Do you need to ignore the values between 0.9 and 9.0, or is it a typo?

Comment: at DYZ I do not know how to taki int account values less than 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

The list or array supplied to `bins` contains the edges of the histogram bins. You may therefore create a bin ranging from the minimal value in `results` to `9.0`.

```
bins = [np.min(results)] + range(9, np.max(results), 1)
plt.hist(results, bins=bins)
```